# migrating XP profiles

Tags: windows-xp, migration

I need to migrate users from an old xp machine to a new one (on a domain btw). We're using PCmover now but I hate this thing, it moves over way too much stuff by default and its a pain to configure. My problem is, if I move a profile over manually, XP will ignore it and create a new one. How do i get XP to just use the profile I'm moving? what is it that it doesn't like about the profile? If I can get that to work I can make a simple script to move over specifically what I want.

Comment: Please post information on what `PC Mover` is exactly

Comment: http://www.laplink.com/pcmover